# Attempted to make equation with maxIF dynamic however end up with errors (in excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an equation that references a dynamic dataset… When referencing these dynamic columns I initially just used the range row 3 to row 2000 (as this range is a lot longer than my actual dataset). Unfortunately when I refresh the data it changes this range and messes up the whole equation… So I attempted to make it dynamic.

The initial equation I wrote (ie referencing row 3 to row 2000) as follows.

```
=IF(MAXIFS($EA$3:$EA$2000,Book1!$C$3:$C$2000,Book1[@[project_id]])=Book2!EA3,MAXIFS($EA$3:$EA$2000,Book1!$C$3:$C$2000,Book1[@[project_id]]),0)
```

This is my attempt at making it dynamic (so I don’t need to keep on fiddling around with the equation):

```
=IF(MAXIFS($EA$3:INDEX($EA$3:$EA$2000,COUNTA($EA$3:$EA$2000)),Book1!$C$3:INDEX($C$3:$C$2000,COUNTA($C$3:$C$2000)),Book1[@[project_id]])=Book2!EA3,MAXIFS($EA$3:INDEX($EA$3:$EA$2000,COUNTA($EA$3:$EA$2000)),Book1!$C$3:INDEX($C$3:$C$2000,COUNTA($C$3:$C$2000)),Book1[@[project_id]]),0)
```

But I get a `#VALUE` error and unsure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ranges passed to `MAXIFS` must be of an equal size, which means that `COUNTA($C$3:$C$2000)` and `COUNTA($EA$3:$EA$2000)` must be equal, which I suspect they are not (you can easily verify).

You are correct to attempt to restrict your ranges, as this in general is good practice: some functions, however, including `MAXIFS`, employ implicit detection of the last-used cells within the ranges passed, effectively meaning that you can get away with referencing entire columns with no detriment to calculation performance. As such, that would be my recommendation to you, i.e. use `$EA:$EA` in place of `$EA$3:$EA$2000`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! The bizarre thing is that all columns are the same length, which really confused me around why i was getting that error. Thanks for the recommendation, i have used that (i don't know why i make it so hard for myself sometimes ha ha)

Comment: But maybe one or both of those columns contains blanks? `COUNTA` doesn't count blanks, so maybe that explains the difference.